# Xcode 4.6 and clang error

Tags: xcode, google-drive-api, llvm, clang

I've justed upgraded Xcode to 4.6 and now my project does not build anymore.

Here the error message :

```
clang: error: unknown warning option '-Wno-pragmas'
Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1
```

[image: error message]

Thanks.

### UPDATE

I don't know if it's an important flag, but I can compile without the error message if I remove this one from GTLTouchStaticLib's Build Settings :

```
-Wno-unknown-pragmas
```

in the **Other Warning Flags**.

A clean is needed before another build.

Answer (score 4):

The error is actually pretty clear, isn't it? Xcode calls `clang` with the option `-Wno-pragma` and `clang` complains that it does not know any such option. Since Xcode is not setting this option by default, you must have manually added this option in the build settings. If you don't really need, just disable/remove it.

What is a bit strange is that `clang` actually does know this option, at least on my system (just like `clang` also knows `-Wno-unknown-pragmas`). So you may want to go to the build log and look up the exact `clang` command line call that Xcode performs. In the build log, you can select the failed build and expand the failed call, which will you give the exact command line call that Xcode performed in attempt to build a source file.

Comment: Thanks Mecki. As you can see in my answer, I've removed this flag and all is fine. But I wonder why Google Team inserted it in their SDK. And all was fine with Xcode 4.5...

Comment: The project has been updated for Xcode 4.6; be sure to use the current library sources.